# PHP mailer not working

Tags: php

Hie am trying to send an email in php but i keep getting this error

Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in C:\wamp\www\Site\php\phpmailer.php on line 2

here is my code below:

```
<?php
$mail  = new PHPMailer();   
$mail->IsSMTP();

//GMAIL configerations
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
$mail->Port       = 465;                   
$mail->Username   = "myaddress@gmail.com"; 
$mail->Password   = "password";           
//End Gmail

$mail->From       = "address@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName   = "Me";
$mail->Subject    = "Trial";
$mail->MsgHTML("this is atest message");


$mail->AddAddress("my address@gmail.com","name to");
$mail->IsHTML(true); 

if(!$mail->Send()) {//to see if we return a message or a value bolean
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else{
  echo "Message sent!";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Include the `PHPMailer` class before you use it.

Comment: PHPMailer is not a built in part of PHP, so you need to include its definition somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the phpmailer class !

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/lib/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
```

http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks a million times, its working proper now

Comment: Excellent solution thanks, was having trouble with paths and this sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the class before you create an instance ? For example:

```
require_once 'C:\PATH\TO\CLASS\PHPMailer.php';
```